# pptx file not opened via Apple Script

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I want to write an Apple Script that converts me Microsoft PowerPoint presentations into PDFs. I started with a small version, but strange enough, already that very short stub fails:

```
on run arguments
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileAlias to POSIX file (first item of arguments) as alias

        tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
            open fileAlias
        end tell

    end tell
end run
```

The argument provided refers to a valid .pptx file. But when calling the script via

```
osascript path/to/script.scpt ~/path/to/file.pptx
```

PowerPoint 2016 opens, but shows an empty presentation instead of the presentation in file.pptx.

When I slightly change the script, it actually opens the file:

```
on run arguments
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileAlias to POSIX file (first item of arguments) as alias  
        open fileAlias      
    end tell
end run
```

Why is the file opened when the open command is not issued within the PowerPoint application block, and is not opened when issued within the block? Is it possibly a timing issue?